# Where can I ask questions about BitTorrent?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

About BitTorrent in general, about client's configuration ([example](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79006/11996)) and related areas?

Because:

- *certainly [is off-topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79006/11996)* at Information Security,
- Stack Overflow isn't a good place, as these question are not about programming,
- *seems* off-topic on Web Applications (because BitTorrent isn't a web application),
- most likely will be closed at Server Fault and Unix & Linux, because isn't about servers.

So? Anywhere? Or off-topic across entire Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) would appear to be [the appropriate place for questions about BitTorrent](https://superuser.com/tags/bittorrent/info).

While [the tag exists on Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) it doesn't really belong. Of the four questions there: two are closed as off-topic; another is a duplicate of one of the off-topic questions; the fourth doesn't really look to be on-topic and will likely be auto-deleted soon.